# Deleting row of obect in a nested array Angular 2/4

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a model that has array inside an array of object:

```
<div *ngFor="let n of shops?.locations let i=index;">
   <span>{{n.name}}</span>
   <button (click)="select(n, i)">select</button>
</div>
<popup>
<div *ngFor="let subloc of locationssub let j=index;">
   <span>{{subloc.id}}</span>
   <span><{{subloc.name}}</span>
   <button  (click)="delete(subloc, j)">del</button>
</div
</popup>
```

In my component I have:

```
 select(n, i){
    this.indexi=i;
    this.locationssub=n;
    this.popup.show();
 }

 delete(subloc, j){
    this.shops.locations[this.indexi].locationssub.splice(j,1);
 }
```

When I run this, it doesn't splice and remove the row. 

How can i fix it?

Comment: Is this code `<button select(n, i)>select</button>` working?  I guess you missed `(click)="..."` binding there

Comment: Sorry it was a type I corrected it. Code is functioning fine just not deleting the row in splice. Thanks

Comment: can you add a console.log(this.shops.locations[this.indexi].locationssub,length) after splice?

Comment: I did and there nothing.  There is no error. Also entry is not deleted. Issue is nested arrays and index seems like

Answer (score 1):

Hello there are two possible reasons for this.

1. Your code does not work (is the entry deleted from your array)
2. Angular does not regonize the changes of your object, so you have to call changedetection after deleting: https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef

Comment: are you sure? why angular does not recognize?

Comment: Code works but entry is not deleted. There is no error either

Comment: Could you please provide an example which produces the same error? You can use https://stackblitz.com/